# Gesture Detector not working inside stack in flutter

Tags: flutter

Createed a showBottomSheet where i want to close it by clicking on GestureDetector..

Instead of sharing entire code i have jsut placed a demo code to explain what i am looking for..

I have two widget inside Stack,, a container for close and a container

i have wrapped close container with GestureDetector but its not getting tap...

here is my code

```
Stack(
            clipBehavior: Clip.none,
            children: [
              Container(
                height: 200,
                width: 200,
                color: Colors.green,
                child: TextButton(onPressed: (){
                  print('Hello');
                },child: Text('A'),),
              ),
              Positioned(
                top: -40,
                child: GestureDetector(
                  onTap: (){
                    print('Bye');
                    Navigator.of(context).pop();
                  },
                  child: Container(
                    height: 40,
                    width: 100,
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        color: Colors.red.shade50,
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                            topLeft: Radius.circular(20),
                            topRight: Radius.circular(20))),
                    child: const Center(
                      child: Text(
                        'Close',
                        style: TextStyle(color: Colors.red),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          )
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class Test extends StatefulWidget {
  const Test({super.key});

  @override
  State<Test> createState() => _TestState();
}


class _TestState extends State<Test> {
  
  
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    
     
    
  return Scaffold(
    appBar: AppBar(
      
    ),
    drawer: Drawer(
    child: customappbar()
    ),
      body: Container(
        padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 50),
        child: TextButton(onPressed: (){
                  print('Hello');
          test(context);
                },child: Text('Hello'),),
     )

    );
  }
}

void test(context){
   showModalBottomSheet(
                    context: context,
       backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
      isDismissible: false,
      enableDrag: false,
                    builder: (context) {
                      return customssappbar();
                    });
}

class customssappbar extends StatelessWidget {
   @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      alignment: Alignment.center,
      child: Stack(
            clipBehavior: Clip.none,
            children: [
              Container(
                 width: 200,
                child: Column(
                children: [
                  SizedBox(
                    height: 40,), // for clickable event
                  Container(
                height: 200,
                width: 200,
                color: Colors.green,
                child: TextButton(onPressed: (){
                  print('Hello');
                },child: Text('A'),),
              ),
                ]
              )),
              
              Positioned(
                top: 0,
                right: 0,
                child: GestureDetector(
                  onTap: (){
                    print('Bye');
                    Navigator.of(context).pop();
                  },
                  child: Container(
                    height: 40,
                    width: 100,
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        color: Colors.red.shade50,
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                            topLeft: Radius.circular(20),
                            topRight: Radius.circular(20))),
                    child: const Center(
                      child: Text(
                        'Close',
                        style: TextStyle(color: Colors.red),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          )
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: want to solve with STack

Comment: hope the above changes will help you